# What would be the height of the given figure below?

Tags: calculus

What would be the height of the given figure below ? what would be the area of width $ \Delta h \ $ at a height $ \ h \ $ ?

[image]

**Answer:**

[image]

From the given figure , I is clear that length of $ AB \ =\frac{6-4}{2}=1 \ $ .

Thus , height $ = \sqrt{8^2-1^1}=\sqrt{63} \ $.

**Am I Right ?**